# HTML/CSS Same line and centered

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for some help!
I want to center some social media images but I also want them on the same line!
I'm working with bootstrap and also want it to be responsive.

This is the HTML-code. I have offcorse 2 other col-lg-4 with other information!

```
<div class="col-lg-4 text-center test">
<hr>
<h4>Följ oss</h4>
<hr>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="twitter" target="_blank"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/smartfeeduf" class="facebook" target="_blank"></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://instagram.com/smartfeed_uf" class="instagram"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="tumblr" target="_blank"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="rss" target="_blank"></a></li>
    <li><a href="kontakt.html" class="email"></a></li>
    </ul>
```

I have tried with this CSS and I it's almost exactly how I want it.

```
.twitter, .facebook, .instagram, .tumblr, .rss, .email{
margin: 5px;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
display:inline-block;

vertical-align: baseline;
text-align:center;}
```

The images are load like this for everyone:

```
.twitter{ background:transparent url(../img/social/twitter-b.png) center top no-repeat;}

.twitter:hover{ background-image: url(../img/social/twitter-dl.png);}
```

When I have all this it shows up like this

[image]

To the right you can see my icons. The only thing I Want to do is put them on the same line. But it didn't work. Please help me :)

Comment: You're setting the `inline-block` to the `anchors`, not `li`. Just put `ul li{display:inline-block}` and it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the styling on the li element.

```
li.social {
    margin: 5px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}

<ul>
    <li class="social"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to your css:

```
li{

    display:inline;

}
```

`li` elements by default will list vertically unless you set them to in-line. You might need to adjust padding/margins after doing this.

Comment: There's no "-" in "inline"

Comment: The display:inline-block; fixed it! Thanks :) I used it under wrong atribute. It should have been written under the "li" istead. Thanks!